# Get the Location Where XDocument was Loaded From

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm working with `XDocument` at the moment and trying to find a property for where the document was originally loaded from:

For example, this will load a file located at url:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
```

To save, I would need to do:

```
XDocument.Save(url)
```

I may need to to pass `doc` to another method in another class and have it save back to that location without passing the url along.

Is the 'url' value stored anywhere within the doc object?

Comment: I guess you tried [`BaseUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.baseuri.aspx) but it did not work, right?

Comment: If you want this information you will have to send it yourself unless http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.baseuri.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 doesn't work for you. In either case clearly not enough research has been done.

Comment: sorry, I have been looking for a while actually but completely missed BaseUri.  Less haste, more speed and all that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`XObject.BaseUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.baseuri.aspx) property.

But not to have it set to `null`, you have to load your document with `LoadOptions.SetBaseUri` set:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url, LoadOptions.SetBaseUri );
```